# Python: If statement not working?

Tags: python, csv

I have a piece of code which doesn't work.

```
if difficulty=="Easy" or "easy" or "1":
    with  open("EasyQs.csv") as f:
        allData = [line.strip().split(",") for line in f]
        questions  = [data[0] for data in allData]
        answers = [data[1] for data in allData]
    print(questions)
if difficulty=="Hard" or "hard" or "2":
    with  open("MediumQs.csv") as f:
        allData = [line.strip().split(",") for line in f]
        questions  = [data[0] for data in allData]
        answers = [data[1] for data in allData]
    print(questions)
```

I try to type 2, hard or Hard but it always prints the questions from the 'easy' CSV? 
Why is this? and how can it be solved?

Comment: use `elif` not `if`.

Comment: In both cases, you open the same file: `EasyQs.csv`

Comment: Now the `or` parts are evaluating to `True` because `if "string"` is `True` unless the string is `""`

Comment: Now that you know why your `if` statements weren't behaving like you expected you should try to reorganize your code so it's less repetitive: just select the file name in the `if` statements and then have a single section where you open the file and process it. You should [try to avoid duplicating code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), when practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, if you want to check if something is one of a set of values, you use this:

```
if difficulty in ("Easy", "easy", "1"):
```

---

The reason is that what you're doing right now doesn't work like you think it does. The conditional you have:

```
if difficulty == "Easy" or "easy" or "1":
```

Actually evaluates like this:

```
if (difficulty == "Easy") or ("easy") or "1":
```

Because `or` is a looser binding operator than `==`. So this overall combined condition will always be true, because `"easy"` is a true value, so even if `(difficulty == "Easy")` is false, the `or` operator will evaluate its right hand side to true and return it.

That's why right now your "easy" case always triggers.

Comment: You should also introduce the `.lower()` function in your answer, so you don't have to type easy twice. ;)

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes maybe, but that's mostly orthogonal to the core point and thus tends to distract from the answer.

Comment: Makes sense. Sticking with the main problem. +1

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes Comments down here are a great place to add extra tips like that, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

`if "string"` is `True`

Try this:

```
if difficulty=="Easy" or difficulty=="easy" or difficulty=="1":
```

Answer (score 1):

In python you don't use more than 1 `if` in an `if-statement`. You need to use `elif` for all ifs after the first `if`. And then `in` makes the difficulty either of the answers. and the `.lower()` makes the users input lower case, so you don't have to do the "Hard" in the choices because it changes it to "hard".

```
if difficulty.lower() in ("easy", "1"):
            with  open("EasyQs.csv") as f:
                allData = [line.strip().split(",") for line in f]
                questions  = [data[0] for data in allData]
                answers = [data[1] for data in allData]
            print(questions)
elif difficulty.lower() in ("hard", "2"):
            with  open("EasyQs.csv") as f:
                allData = [line.strip().split(",") for line in f]
                questions  = [data[0] for data in allData]
                answers = [data[1] for data in allData]
            print(questions)
```

Comment: It is not the case that you need to use `elif` for all `if`s after the first.

Comment: @davejagoda when would you use another `if` after the first? I never knew you could.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes I can think of at least 2 reasons - one is you know that the conditions are mutually exclusive. Another is you are going to exit, break, or return during one if statement, and thus if the first if is True, you won't reach the subsequent one.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

```
if difficulty=="Easy" or "easy" or "1":
```

is seen as

```
if (difficulty=="Easy") or ("easy") or ("1"):
```

Non-empty strings are interpreted as `True`, so your expression is actually:

```
if difficulty=="Easy" or True or True:
```

Which will always be `True`. To resolve the problem, use something like this:

```
if difficulty.lower().strip() in ('easy', '1'):
```

This will convert the test to lowercase, strip leading and trailing spaces off and see if that fits an item in the given tuple of values.

Answer (score -1):

Your second if statement must be an 'elif' statement as you have already created and if statement.

Comment: That's not necessarily true - suppose I know the if statements are mutually exclusive?