# Else not coming into effect in small program

Tags: python

I've tried to make a program that randomizes meals and outputs a random dish. The only problem is, when it first asks you if you want a dish it returns a dish no matter what the response it. Any help appreciated.

```
print('Random Dinner Dish?')
response = input()
while True:

    if response == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Y' or 'y':
        print(dinner[random.randint(0,len(dinner) - 1)])
        break
    else:
        print('Goodbye')
        break
```

I'm expecting it to print Goodbye and stop the program if some form of yes isn't used.

Comment: `or` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: You can't string the `or`s like that. This is a better way to test this: `if response in ['Yes','yes','Y','y']:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: If statement not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454387/python-if-statement-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python if with many or in a contracted form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681028/python-if-with-many-or-in-a-contracted-form)

Answer (score 0):

The result of `response == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'Y' or 'y'` is always truthy, so the else-block is unreachable.

You probably meant

```
if response in {'Yes', 'yes', 'Y', 'y'}:
```

---

`or` will return its left side if it is truthy, otherwise it returns its right.

So `False or 'yes'` returns `'yes'`.

Comment: Thanks,works now. Why doesn't or work in this situation?

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for the help.